# rewriting module ".htacess"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to activate rewriting features on my MVC, I got "500 Internal Server Error", this is my code on .htacess file:

[image: Screenshot of code]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: You don't have any _spaces_ between your arguments?!

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, I just did some research on .htaccess and now I understand why I got this error, it was just a missing space, I thank you again.